# Finding an area of the farm in cm2 on the map

Tags: area

So the area of the map is 2000 hectares but the question is asking to find the area of the farm in cm2. I'm a bit confused as how to work this out. I know that 1 hectare is equals to 10,0000 m2.

The scale of the map is 1: 180,000

Comment: Do you know how to convert hectares to square meters? You stated that you do. Do you know how to convert square meters to square centimeters? That should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An hectare is $10^4$ square metres. A square metre is $(100)^2=10^4$ square cm. So the field has $2\times 10^{11}$ square cm.

The *linear* scale is $180000$ to $1$. So $1$ square cm on the map represents $(180000)^2$ square cm on the ground.

Thus on the map, the area of the farm is $\frac{10^{11}}{(180000)^2}$ square cm.

**Remark:** If the linear dimensions of an object are scaled by the scale factor $\lambda$, then area is scaled by the factor $\lambda^2$, and volume is scaled by the factor $\lambda^3$. In our case, $\lambda=\frac{1}{180000}$.